# Is there a hibernate plugin for netbeans version 11.0?

Tags: hibernate, netbeans, plugins

I work with **netbeans version 11.0** and i can't find hibernate plugin for it, how can i add hibernate to my project or to my ide?

Comment: Your project is with maven?

Comment: No not maven,! with maven will works ??

Comment: To activate the Hibernate plugin: [1] Go to **Tools > Plugins** and then click the **Available Plugins** tab. [2] Locate the **Hibernate** plugin in the list of plugins. [3] Check the **Install** checkbox for that entry, then click the **Install** button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 ways, the first one is that you create your project with Maven and add the Maven repository to pom.xml
Like this:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: [1] The OP explicitly told you that their project was not a Maven project, so why give a Maven based solution? [2] **Delete the link in your answer, It triggers a download.**

Comment: Since you didn't remove the link in your answer that was triggering a download I have.

Answer (score 4):

Open netbeans 11 go to tools -> plugin
go to settings -> click on plugin portal
go to availible plugin click on check for newest
look for hibernate and done

add hibernate to the project

Answer (score 0):

First download hibernate framework from official site and then extract it
After In that extracted folder there will be dist folder inside that there will be three jar files add that files to your project libraries.
Then in that extracted folder there will be required folder inside lib folder , in that there will be four jar files , add that jar files to your libraries folder of your project.

Now setup is ready